# Magento 2 : Render Options HTML

Tags: magento2

I've Magento 1.x code. I would like to use in Magento2.x version.

What it would be ??

Code :

```
<?php $_options = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getOptions()) ?>
    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<?php else: echo dlkghflghf;?>
```

I need to relevant code to Render HTML for options.

What I can use for `<?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>` In Magento 2 ?